# Which file end to use for binary files?

Tags: c#, serialization

I discovered that I could save a binary file, just by it's name and without any extension. Which extension should I use? .dat?

Comment: The word is "extension" and it can be anything you want.  Just give it something reasonable (e.g., not `.txt`).

Comment: Thanks! Extension was a better word!

Comment: Better if you use .Bin to Differentiate it better from other files..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose any extension that you want, could be your initials, could be *.Dat, could be *.bin or a full name

Answer (score 3):

You can use any extension, that shouldn't confuse anyone (e.g. "jpg", "htm" or "docx" is a bad idea)."dat" is fine, just like "bin" or some 3 letters from the name of your application :-) Or you can use no extension at all if you don't need to make later file associations with your program.

Comment: +1 for "use no extension if you don't need file associations".

Comment: @Earlz: People used extensions long before there were file associations (e.g. DOS).  It helps to understand the nature of the file two years down the road when your old client calls up and asks for a bug fix.

Comment: @EricJ. It seems that only Windows developers use extensions for relatively "properietary" binary files. In the *nix world file extensions are only used when that type of file is intended to be edited or used by more than 1 program. (with some exceptions, such as makefile and such)

Comment: True, but this is targeting Windows and it is reasonable to follow Windows conventions.

Answer (score 2):

While you can use any extension you like (or no extension at all) I would stay away from using extensions that the system will interpret to be a different type of file (e.g. don't use .exe, .dll, .com, .xls, .doc, .html, .txt, and so forth).

Something like .bin or .dat are descriptive and should not conflict with other naming conventions.